# How to 'Remove' bugs from the backlog from VS Online using Agile process template

Tags: azure-devops

We have a project on VS online that uses the Agile process template. We have configured this project to

[image: show bugs on the backlog]

.

If I create a bug, I can't unfortunately delete it afterward. The 'State' dropdown only includes the 'New', 'Closed', 'Active' and 'Resolved' values. This does not match with what Microsoft documents in the [following page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997897.aspx). If you look at the section labeled 'Q: What workflow states does Agile support?', it says that you can go from 'New' to 'Removed'.

Why I am not able to do this change? What can I do to remove bugs that were created by mistake or that were simply not valid?

Note that I am the administrator of the project.

Comment: Are you using an on-prem server or are you using Visual Studio Online?

Comment: As already mentioned in the post, we are using VS online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about the confusion. The Removed state is not part of the Agile Process Template, and we will update the documentation to reflect this.

We will also fix the product moving forward to allow to remove bugs on the backlog. Keep an eye to the [release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso) (and subscribe to the rss feed) to learn when we have fixed it.

Ewald Hofman (TFS/VSO Program Manager)

Comment: Thanks Ewald. It will be very helpful to be able to remove bugs. Until then, we will add a new iteration named "Thrash" and move all the bugs that we want to delete in this iteration path. We will also modify our configuration so that this iteration is not shown in the backlog.

Answer (score 1):

I can get the same behavior with you, so I help you submit a feedback on Microsoft Connect website, you can track the feedback from this link:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1986844

For now, you can delete the bug via destroywi command:

```
witadmin destroywi /collection:https://<your project>.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection /id:<bug ID>
```

Comment: MS Connect has been retired, so removing/replacing this link would be helpful.